# Pass data to a BackgroundServiceAgent

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, agent

I have two projects, one of them is a "Windows phone application" and the other is a "Windows phone Audio player Agent".

In order to provide the AudioPlayer with something like "the next track" I need a way to communicate between my application and the agent.

My first attempt was a singleton, I don't know exactly why, but both of them create their own instance of the singleton.

So what is the best/easiest way to communicate ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The [MSDN Sample about Audio Agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202978%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) explains precisely how to do this.

Comment: How do you mean this, they assume there that the given tracks are already on the IslolatedStorage and that they know which track is going to be played next. But I have allot of different Playlists and different tracks which are not necessarily on the IsolatedStorage.

So I need a way to say the AudioPlayer Agent which playlist he should play, and if he should shuffle and/or repeat

Comment: I think you need to read a lot more up about background agents in general, before you continue with this.

Comment: providing example of how this can be made when you get tracks dynamically (through some API, and not having them locally) would greatly improve your answer

Comment: And writing his entire app would also do improve the answer I guess.